# Java new array value per number

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a program (code shown below) where the user can input a string with numbers. These are then converted from a string to an integer. But what I really want is a new array, where each individual number is a value. So if the user writes "15623" I want the array to be like {1, 5, 6, 2, 3}
Does anyone know how to do it?

```
String getNumbers = textField.getText();                            
String[] ary = getNumbers.split(" ");
int intNumbers = Integer.parseInt(getNumbers);

int iArr[] = {intNumbers};
Arrays.sort(iArr);
for (int number : iArr) {
    textField.setText("" + number);
}
```

Comment: `getNumbers.split("")` without space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `charAt` to get specific characters and `getNumericValue` to convert a character to a digit :

```
String nums="1235325";
int[]  iArr = new int[nums.length ()];
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length (); i++) {
  iArr[i]=Character.getNumericValue (nums.charAt (i));
}
Arrays.sort (iArr);
System.out.println (Arrays.toString (iArr));
```

Output :

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5]
```

Comment: I really love you. Thanks a lot! Tons of love!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi if i understood the question you just need to split your input string on "" rather than " ".

```
String[] ary = getNumbers.split("");//This array will now look like {"1", "5", "6", "2", "3"}
```

Edit: Fixed output appearance

Comment: No. It looks like `{"1", "5", "6", "2", "3"}`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
int iArr[] = new int[numString.length()];
for(int i=0;i<numString.length();i++)
     iArr[i]=Character.getNumericValue(numString.chatAt(i))
```